# How can I display “Like what you see?” at Windows login?

Tags: windows-10, login-screen, windows-spotlight

As I log into Windows 10, there is usually a different background picture each time on the login page, and I am prompted do you "Like what you see?" in the top right corner, but only if it's not prompting me for my password. Once the password input is displayed I know of no method to get back to "Like what you see?" except to log in and then lock Windows (e.g. <kbd>Start</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>).

[image: Like what you see?]

If "Like what you see?" is displayed and you click almost anywhere else on the login page, it hides this and shows the login prompt instead.

[image: Login prompt]

All the searches I've done bring up results saying "The login page is so annoying! How do I disable it?" I don't find it annoying and I don't mind sending feedback as it does seem to no longer show me pictures I don't like.

Is it possible to get straight from the log in prompt to the "Like what you see?" prompt without logging in, waiting several minutes for it to time out, etc?

Comment: Are you asking how to enabled Windows Spotlight?  You don’t indicate if you have a version of Windows 10 which supports it.

Comment: This is the way Microsoft has designed the "Like what you see" UI for Windows Spotlight. This system is poorly understood right now, from what I can tell online, and there aren't any ways I'm familiar with of hacking it. I would guess that besides the methods you have already described it is NOT possible to arbitrarily bring up the dialog.

Comment: @CJDennis Wouldn’t have know what your question was without those images

Comment: I do not know the option on how to have Spotlight react the way you want but I know this [URL](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AFZR%2DmBodwPk7Zw&id=BB630614D0FFAB00%212123&cid=BB630614D0FFAB00) if you just want to get the pictures without using Spotlight.

Comment: Changing from Picture to Spotlight and then going to the Lock Screen displays the Like question each time in my case. You might want to try that.

Comment: In recent builds, I've noticed the Spotlight picture now additionally blurs when prompting for your password.. If you wait 30 seconds or so, the login box disappears and you go back to the Spotlight, although this is probably slower than logging in and locking again.  What would really make sense is just to be able to press Escape there.

Comment: 5-years later: the 'like what you see' question vanished again recently. Suggested solutions for re-activation failed (at least on my end, Windows 10 Pro, 22H2, build 19045.2846, Feature Exp Pack 120.2212.4190.0). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and this helped me.

In Personalization->Lock Screen settings change Background to Picture. Minimise this window Go to the following folder, select all files inside that folder, then move them to the Recycle Bin and permanently delete:

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_<somerandomcharacters>\Settings
```

Expand the window with the Personalization->Lock Screen settings. Change Background back to Windows Spotlight. Sign out and the Spotlight "Like what you see?" box should be there...

Comment: Restart was needed on my PC.

Comment: It sounds like this is solving a different problem?  In the Question, the problem is that once you've clicked on the lock screen, the Spotlight stuff vanishes until you log in and back out.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, this trick (with/without Restart) did not recover "Like what you see?", which has been lost for more than a year by now.

Comment: Not working for my windows 10 today 2020 May

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and wasn't finding solutions on Google but ended up figuring it out and it's very simple. Go to Personalization then lock screen. Make sure Windows spotlight is selected. Then disable "Show lock screen background picure on the sign-in screen". Lock your computer or sign out and "Like what you see?" will be there. After you get to your login prompt, if you don't login or click on the screen it will return to the Spotlight "Like what you see" after 60 seconds of inactivity.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I was asking. See the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: After you get to your login prompt, if you don't login or click on the screen it will return to the Spotlight "Like what you see" after 60 seconds of inactivity

Comment: Add that to your answer, please, so that it is complete

Comment: I think it's more like 30 seconds now, they might have changed it...

Answer (score 0):

You can also find this folder that keeps this windows spotlight background login wallpaper through simple click through navigation -- ***C: > Users > [your username] > AppData > Local > Packages > Microsoft. Windows. ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy > LocalState > Assets*** -- but you'll need to make hidden files visible and rename the file to extension .jpg by copying the file to pictures folder for example :-)

Comment: Instead of a temporary comment you should edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the login screen I click Esc. The login prompt shows up. I ignore it and then the 'Do you like it' comes up on the screen.

Comment: How long does it take to get back to 'Do you like it'? 60 or 30 seconds of waiting? What about the way of how to return there immediately from the password prompt?

Answer (score 0):

well if you do not want to wait for the timeout, log in and log out again with windows button + L. it will go right to the locked screen without login prompt displaying

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the Lock-Screen settings and disable the option "Choose one app to show detailed status on the lock screen" (select "none" to disable it)

It looks like every single option in the Lock-Screen menu has been blamed in this thread, but I have just tested this and assure you that this works.